# Getting a MVC2 variable into Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, variables

I am attempting to manipulate an asp.net MVC2 view variable in Jquery...

```
(function () {
    debugger;
    var $a = 10;
    var $b = '<%:toggle %>';
    var $c = 12;
});
```

As you may have guessed, I am attempting to manipulate the toggle variable that I have initiated in an ASP.net MVC2 view in Jquery.

What I did above doesn't seem to work at all.  The page that I attempt to load, blows up every time I try and open it.  Any ideas why that might be?  Note... Even if I get rid of the ' ' (apostrophes) my page still blows up.  I also attempted to make the variable in question public.  That doesn't seem to work either.

***UPDATE EXPECTED vs WHAT I GET***
I don't expect to get this...

[image: my page with that value set to the variable in the view that I described earlier]

Here is what I do expect
[image: my page when I set the variable equal to 11 or something trivial]

I am having a hard time getting the error message that is being sent to the page.  I have to figure out where its being generated and try and chase it down from there.  My coworker set up some kind of Javascript error routing scenario for this particular page.  And I am having a little trouble deciphering what is going on.  If I knew the error I would probably be in good shape.

***UPDATE 2 Just figured out the error***

TemplateInfo.aspx(371): error CS0103: The name 'toggle' does not exist in the current context...

I am guessing that variable has to be somehow made public or put into scope somehow.  How can.  To my knowledge you can't create public variables with MVC2?  Can you?

Comment: What happens? What's the generated source?

Comment: It blows? That's a very descriptive problem description. Balloons usually blow. Not working source code usually generates error messages or does not behave as expected when run.

Comment: Note you are using `<%: %>` to render the variable toggle.  This produces a value that has been HTML Encoded.  Is that what you intended.  Otherwise you may want to use `<%= %>` which will just render the value.

Comment: @John Harsock.  Tride the above aswell.  It didn't seem to work.  Darin Dimitrov.  I meant to wirte blows up.  The Page just doesn't load correctly.  I am guessing an error is thrown back to the page.  I can't figure out where it is occuring.

Comment: @DmainEvent, what do you mean by `The Page just doesn't load correctly`? Define what you expect and then explain what you observe. Screen shots could be welcome. Also are you getting some error messages in the console? How does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: Made some of the changes you suggested.  I am trying to get the generated HTML, but a coleage of mine did some weird Javascript error handling that I am trying to decipher.  I will get it to you if and when I get it.

Comment: Where does `toggle` come from? Where is it defined? You can pass data from your controller to you view in many different ways.

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong. I had a couple of content panes.  In one I defined content in the other I had my scripts. That's where I was attempting to manipulate the variable.  Once I got the value into that the content pane, I no longer got that exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `toggle` variable that you are trying to use is nowhere defined in your view.

In ASP.NET MVC controller actions normally pass view models to views. Those view models contain properties that will be used by the view. So as always in an ASP.NET MVC application you start by defining a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public bool IsToggle { get; set; }
}
```

then you write a controller action which instantiates this view model and passes it to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        IsToggle = true
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally you write a strongly typed view to this view model where you can use its properties:

```
<%@ Page 
    Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<AppName.Models.MyViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        debugger;
        var $a = 10;
        var $b = <%= Model.IsToggle %>;
        var $c = 12;
    });    
    </script>

</asp:Content>
```

Now let's suppose that your view model contains some properties that are of type string or even other complex objects. In this case you will need to properly encode them. And the best way to ensure that you are properly encoding values that you are passing to javascript is to  use javascript literals (JSON notation):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
    debugger;
    // we JSON serialize the entire model:
    var model = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model) %>;

    // Now you can manipulate individual model properties:
    alert(model.SomeProperty);
});    
</script>
```

Note that the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class is defined in the `System.Web.Extensions` assembly in the `System.Web.Script.Serialization` namespace so make sure to bring those into scope.

Comment: Good answer, thorough with good example.  If I were using strongly typed views and a well defined model driven MVC site, I would definitely take your suggestions into advisements.  My model is pretty much an XML string.  I could pass it directly to the view, but I had a hard time doing that so I just put it into a ViewData[] object.  But this is good documentation for the MVC un-initiated.  thanks.

Comment: My problem was that I had this toggle variable defined out of scope of the jquery function.  Apperently, ASP:content panes have a scope in an MVC view.  Didn't know that.  I placed the variable in the correct ASP:content pane and viola.  Again thanks.