# Show different button on page load via Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an ASP.net MVC2 site that I have designed.  I have a small design issue.  I want a button to change when the view loads.  For instance when a certain variable equals a certain value I want one button to show up and another button to disappear.  What I have so far is basically a jquery implementation of that idea.  But so far, my jquery code is not getting called (I have a debugger statement set inside the jquery so I know it's not getting called).  I have tried to place the code in a $(document).ready(function()... and a $(document).load(function()...

the code still doesn't load.  here is what I tried.

```
$(document).load(function(){           
        var $b = <%=toggle %>;
        var buttonTog = $("#test1");
        var buttonTog1 = $("#Submit1");
        if($b=="1")
        {
            debugger;
            buttonTog1.css({
                display: 'block'
            })
            buttonTog.css({
                display: 'none'
            });
        }
        else if($b=="0")
        {
            debugger;
            buttonTog1.css({
                display: 'none'
            })
            buttonTog.css({
                display: 'block'
            });
        }   
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    //debugger;
    ShowMessage();
    (function () {           
        var $b = <%=toggle %>;
        var buttonTog = $("#test1");
        var buttonTog1 = $("#Submit1");
        if($b=="1")
        {
            debugger;
            buttonTog1.css({
                display: 'block'
            })
            buttonTog.css({
                display: 'none'
            });
        }
        else if($b=="0")
        {
            debugger;
            buttonTog1.css({
                display: 'none'
            })
            buttonTog.css({
                display: 'block'
            });
        }            
    });
    ...
    });
```

What I intend to do is check the value of a variable that I get from a ViewData field, and based upon what that value is make the css display attribute of one button or the other be either none or block depending upon circumstances of course.  What is the best way to get Jquery code to run when a page first fires?  And how would you implement such a scheme?  Is this the best way to get this done, or should I consider redesigning how I implement this feature?  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to clean your code a little. Let's suppose that toggle is a boolean variable defined previously in the page although [this is bad and you should use view models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126280/getting-a-mvc2-variable-into-jquery/8127330#8127330):

```
<% bool toggle = true; %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var buttonTog = $("#test1");
        var buttonTog1 = $("#Submit1");
        var toggle = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(toggle) %>;
        if (toggle) {
            buttonTog1.show();
            buttonTog.hide();
        } else {
            buttonTog1.hide();
            buttonTog.show();
        }
    });
</script>
```

But assuming you have this information on the server (and you have it since you are defining the toggle variable on the server) I would recommend you directly applying the corresponding CSS classes to the given buttons on the server. This way you don't even need to use any javascript at all. Simply:

```
<button type="submit" id="test1" class="<%= Html.ToggleClass(toggle) %>">Test1</button>
<button type="submit" id="Submit1" class="<%= Html.ToggleClass(!toggle) %>">Submit1</button>
```

where `ToggleClass` would be a custom HTML helper returning the correct CSS class name based on the parameter value:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static string ToggleClass(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, bool toggle)
    {
        return toggle ? "visible" : "hidden";
    }
}
```

and finally in your CSS file:

```
.visible {
    display: block;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Interesting implementations.  Both the first and the second.  On the second implementation, where would I be calling ToggleClass?  Obviously on the server.  I would then pass this string to the view?  Again, interesting answer.

Comment: @DmainEvent, in the second case you would define a static class `HtmlExtensions` for example in an Extensions folder on your project. Then you will bring the namespace into which this class is declared into scope in the view and you will have access to the ToggleClass custom helper. It's the standard way all helpers work.

Comment: I actually implemented your first suggestion.  It worked.  Your second suggestion will be in the back of my head though for future assignments.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change following

```
var $b = <%=toggle %>;
```

to

```
var b = '<%=toggle %>';

if(b=="1"){
$("#Submit1").hide()
}
```

Comment: Well, I suppose that is fine.  But I need to figure out why my function never gets called.  When debugging it just steps right over.  Never even gets called.

Answer (score 0):

there is an easier way, just give a class "visible" to the buttons that are meant ro be visible, and "hidden" to the ones that arent meant to be seen, then you can do whatever you want with them using jquery or css